# Intersection between points and polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, intersection, point-in-polygon

I have two shapefiles: points and polygons.

I want to know what points (not how many) fall inside each of the polygons of my MultiPolygon shapefile.

I thought the "Intersect" function was the best option to deal with this, but actually it seems that it is implemented to intersect only polygons with polygons. In fact if I try to run it I get an empty table.

Has any other function been implemented to deal with this issue?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to original poster, the simple **intersect function does work** for capturing points in polygons, in newer version of QGIS (2.14.3-Essen). Using this method also gives you the attribute data common to both datasets as well.

Answer (score 4):

go to>>>vector>>Analysis Tools>>>Points in Polygon option:[image]

Answer (score 1):

As for [@Arun's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71251/115). I think given that the question has been asked twice in different form that there is some degree of unclarity.

If you want to select all points within an entire layer.  For example I want to select all SAC's within AONB (Planning terms and designated areas...not important what they are just that they are all seperate entities on larger shapefiles). I would use vector > Spatial Query > Spatial Query.  The table which appears allows me to select from contain, equals, within....etc. So i select within and it generates the results. You can do a few things here but most likely you want to save the list as a layer. so click the button or come out and right lick the layer and save selection as.

if it is, for example, bird nesting grounds within the XYX AONB then i would specifically select each individual area which i am concerned with, and save as an individual layer and complete the task again.  by selecting i mean query the layer or search in the attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using "Data Management tools > Join attributes by location" function (defining "intersect" option). This how you will get the values with which polygon every point intersects with. Later you can do statistics based on these values stored in the attribute table.