# Points within polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, point-in-polygon

I have a shapefile with polygons. And I have a csv file with points.
Now I want to know for each point in which polygon it is situated. Every polygon has a number, so I want to create a file where you can find for each point the number of the polygon it is located in.

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86444/how-to-spatially-join-polygon-fields-onto-a-point-layer-in-qgis

Comment: I smell a duplication

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to import the points, and make sure they have the same coordinate system.
Then you can use intersect to find out for each point in what polygon it is located.
See this topic also. [Intersection between points and polygons in QGis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71250/intersection-between-points-and-polygons-in-qgis)

Answer (score -1):

This requires a few steps;
1. Transform your CSV to a shapefile using the add delimited layer [Here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/fr/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html)

Then merge your point layer to the polygon layer using spatial location :[see here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/fr/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html)

Now each point has its polygon attributes.