# Extracting coordinates from shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile and spatial coordinate file. I wish to extract information for each coordinate from shapefile. 
Is it possible in QGIS?

I have 19 coordinate points and I'm trying to extract soil type data for each coordinate. Shapefile is polygon and coordinate file is .txt. I'm trying to extract information precisely for each coordinate.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? Is your shapefile points, lines or polygons? Are you trying to get the shapefile information for each coordinate precisely in the coordinate file or the nearest? or is it that you want to find the coordinates in the file that match *something* in the shapefile? What format is the coordinate file?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Sample data and desired output?

Comment: If the text file is comma separated values (CSV), have a read of http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html to understand how OGR can use the coordinates without too much mucking around, after you've loaded the points as shape in QGIS then have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71250/intersection-between-points-and-polygons-in-qgis which will explain how to intersect the points and polygons to get the attributes from the polygons for each point.. have a go at that and if you're successful edit your answer to include your steps and some screenshots for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by  @Michael Stimson, if the point data in text format or CSV format you need to import them into QGIS. To do that, here is the process:

- Import them using Add Delimited Text Layer [image]
- Choose the correct delimiter, X Field and Y Field
- Save the file as shapefile and choose the correct CRS that matches the polygon shapefile

[image]

- Now, there are different methods to extract polygon attribute into the point shapefile:

a. Using `Intersect` tool from `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> intersect`

b. Using [Add polygon attributes to points](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/shapes_points/addpolygonattributestopoints.html) tools from `SAGA -> Vector point tools -> Add polygon attributes to points`

c. Using `Join attributes by location` from `Vector -> Data Management tools -> Join attributes by location`.